# How to enable the disabled button when the textbox is already filled with data

Tags: c#

```
private void UserForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUsername.Text != "" || txtPassword.Text != "" || txtID.Text != "" || txtFirstName.Text != "" || txtMiddleName.Text != "" || txtLastName.Text != "" || txtDep.Text != "")
    {
        btnNext.Enabled = true;
    }

    else
    {
        btnNext.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I was trying to make a form where the button is disabled and once the `textboxes` filled up with data, the button will be enabled.

The problem is, the button is disabled even the textboxes is already filled with data.

Comment: Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you and they both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you might be populating the control later and  checking  the  text boxes first in the code.

The code to enable and disable the controls should  be called after the controls get populated with  the values. So, you just need to call your code at  right time.

Comment: Beat me to it :) +1

Comment: @JosephSerido i am not that fast, don't know how you got beaten :P

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not checking if you should enable the button OnChange of the text field each time. You are checking only on  `UserForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

This is what you need:

```
private void textBox__TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUsername.Text != "" || txtPassword.Text != "" || txtID.Text != "" || txtFirstName.Text != "" || txtMiddleName.Text != "" || txtLastName.Text != "" || txtDep.Text != "")
    {
        btnNext.Enabled = true;
    }

    else
    {
        btnNext.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```